# Black lines when compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am attempting to composite a back plate, and blender environment and also the main blender scene. I seem to have manged this with render passes but I am getting a thin black line around the foreground image I am compositing. Any ideas how to how get rid of the black line? I attach a screen shot and compositor nodes to show the problem. Thank you. [image]

[image: Using the Alpha Over node]

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding the alpha settings of the Color Mix node. Use an Alpha Over node instead.
Check Captain Disillusions rant on Blender and alpha channel on Youtube if you want to find out more in a hilarious way.

Comment: That helped - thank you. Revised node tree posted above to show answer in action.

Comment: @Starfury359 Frederik suggested the correct answer, which is the alpha over node. You still show a mix. Use the alpha over and you will be fine.

Comment: @troy_s in the second image I use the Alpha Over node as suggested by Frederick and this indeed solved the issue - there are no mix nodes. The firsts image is before I learnt about the Alpha Over node. Thanks.